# Slide section based on the anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to create a view that can be slided based on the anchor link clicked.

Here is the sample image on how it is supposed to look.
When clicked on appropriate link it is slided left and displays the specific text associated with it.
It also has back button to take back to the previous view.
[image]

Here is the sample fiddle to play with - https://jsfiddle.net/0agfjh5t/5/

```
<div class="slider-view">
  <div class="first-slide">
    <a href="#first">FIRST VIEW</a>
    <a href="#second">SECOND VIEW</a>
    <a href="#third">THIRD VIEW</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-slide">
    <div id="first">
      This should be displayed slided to view when 'FIRST VIEW' anchor is linked
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      This should be displayed slided to view when 'SECOND VIEW' anchor is linked
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      This should be displayed slided to view when 'THIRD VIEW' anchor is linked
    </div>
  </div>
  <a>Go back to FIRST SLIDE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript you have attempted? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Wesley, I was able to show and hide the div's, but confused on how to implement the sliding thing. Updated the Jsfiddle.

Comment: I think your question is too broad and has a wide variety of solutions. Try adding/removing CSS classes to `first-slide` and `second-slide` when an item is clicked. Apply styles like negative margins and transition with easing.

Comment: did you try this tutorial?  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Answer (score 0):

this is not exact solution which you want but it should give you the idea regarding how you can achive a Slideshow / Carousel effect using vanilla JS and CSS. here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5j3db7e/) as well

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.slider-view {
  .first-slide {
    background: lightgrey;
    a {
      display: block;
      color: green;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
  .second-slide {
    > div {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin: 0 }
.mySlides { display: none; }
img { vertical-align: middle; }

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-view">
  <div class="first-slide">
  <a href="#first" onclick="currentSlide(1)">&lt;- Back</a>
  <a href="#first" onclick="currentSlide(1)"><span class='dot'></span>FIRST VIEW</a>
    <a href="#second" onclick="currentSlide(2)"><span class='dot'></span>SECOND VIEW</a>
    <a href="#third" onclick="currentSlide(3)"><span class='dot'></span>THIRD VIEW</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-slide slideshow-container">
    <div id="first" class="mySlides fade">
      This should be displayed 'FIRST VIEW' anchor is linked
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="  mySlides fade">
      This should be displayed 'SECOND VIEW' anchor is linked
    </div>
    <div id="third" class="  mySlides fade">
      This should be displayed 'THIRD VIEW' anchor is linked
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```